# Unable to set up CUDA in MS Visual C++ Express 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, build, cuda

I was using [this link](http://planetanacreon.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/cuda-5-0-with-visual-studio-2010/) to set up my CUDA project on Visual C++ 2010 Express. I was able to complete the first 3 steps. But, I could not complete the 4th step, because in Item Type, there is no **CUDA C/C++** option.

Can you tell me what might be wrong?

[image]

I was able to get the CUDA option in Build Customizations. So, I think that CUDA toolkit 5.0 installed fine.

Comment: Could [this](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/archives/109) help?

Comment: If you have VS 2010 express installed on your machine, and then you install CUDA 5.0, you should be able to build the samples.  Can you build the samples?  This should tell you if your CUDA 5 install has been successful.  Please follow the sequence given in the [getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html) and then indicate at which point you were not able to continue.  The sequence is: 1. install VS 2010, 2. install CUDA 5 3. attempt to run one or more samples 4. attempt to compile and build one or more samples

Answer (score 1):

Sorry
Have you ever considered just adding the address of executable, include, and library manually?

in the new project, rightclick project, properties, Linker, General. in additional library directory = insert the library of cuda : (example)C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v3.2\lib\Win32 (or win64 if you use 64bit). Then Below General there is Input. Insert cudart.lib cuda.lib there.

then in option projects vc/c++ directories insert the following:
- executables : (example installation in winxp) C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v3.2\bin
- library : (example installation in winxp) 
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 3.2\shared\inc
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 3.2\C\common\inc
- include : (example installation in winxp) 
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 3.2\shared\lib

oh and yeah, dont forget the custom build rule.

you can find the complete tutorial here, you can also use this step in vs2010
http://digitalerr0r.wordpress.com/2010/12/19/parallel-computing-using-the-gpu-tutorial-3-integrate-cuda-3-2-into-visual-studio-2008/

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click the project name, select "**Build Customizations...**";
2. Select the CUDA version you have installed, like this:
   [Build Customizations...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEBCp.png)
3. Right click the .cu file, select "**Properties**". Then you can find the "**CUDA C/C++**" option in the Item Type:
   [Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3acCE.png)